# Calculating volumes using integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Given $y=x,y=0,x=2$ and $x=7$. Calculate the volume6 about $x=1$.

I just need to get the concept right. Please tell me what mistake I did here.

The region looks like a trapezium right?

From $y=0$ to $y=2$, it's volume is a larger cylinder - smaller cylinder.

Which is $π(6^2)(2) - π(1^2)(2)$.

For $y=2$ to $y=7$,

I use the $A(y) = π(6)^2 - π(1+y)^2$ and then integrate $A(y)$ from $y=2$ to $y=7$ [outer radius - inner radius]

I can't seem to get the answer and I have a feeling my $A(y)$ is wrong. Can someone tell me which part of it is wrong?

Comment: I think the inner radius at height $y$ ($2$ to $7$) is $y-1$.

Comment: Damn! How could I do such a mistake. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome.  By the way, it is easier to use cylindrical shells, integrate $2\pi x(x-1)$ from $x=2$ to $x=7$.